# how do you model a dipole which absorbs radiation and then emits it , in COMSOL

Tags: dipole

I want to model an oscillating dipole in a 2.45 refractive indexed material. The dipole should absorb waves of frequency 80-100 THz and oscillate and then emits the radiation.
Or in other words the dipole oscillates in that range.

I want to  know the boundary conditions suitable for it , also I want to plot the electric field emitting from the dipole.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but I wonder if there's any update you can give us after all these months? Also, are you still actively in need of an answer to this question? Please update us!